распознавания адресов/геоданных из текста
Столкнулся с задачей: нужно извлекать адреса и геоданные (например, координаты или адреса) из текстов, которые пишут пользователи в жалобах. Тексты могут содержать описания улиц, домов, ориентиров и даже неточные формулировки.
Какие есть проверенные методы, библиотеки или подходы для решения подобной задачи? Интересуют варианты на различных языках программирования (особенно Python), включая машинное обучение и регулярные выражения. Буду благодарен за любые советы, рекомендации или ссылки на готовые решения!

Есть идея выделять улицы, дома по ключевым словам. Для этого вам необходимо составить ключевые слова местностей: тех же самых домов и улиц. Затем сравниваете сходства ваших ключевых слов и ключевых слов из текста пользователя, и на основании совпадений выдаёте адрес. Другой вопрос, как собрать столько данных для проверки совпадений, как контролировать их актуальность.

Идея хорошая. Возьму на заметку, но может есть еще какие-нибудь другие пути решения?
